# what is the cause whereby compressor working gets hot and stops, after cooled down picks up

Tags: hvac, refrigerator

My challenge was that, I have this refrigerator I'm working on and after awhile it is working and then the condenser become hot as the compressor discharges excess heat, which as time goes on immediately stops working and has to be put off for awhile, just to cool down before putting back on. I thought may be it might be drier, which I did change, yet the excess heat persist. So what could be the cause for this.

Comment: What's the ambient temperature when you're running the fridge? Also, is the heat sink/exchanger clean, or clogged full of stuff?

Comment: *Why* does it over heat? It doesn't really matter: the compressor's shot. (prob some bearing surface is worn)

Comment: The 2 things that come to mind are non compressibles in the system and over charge since you replaced the dryer. If the system was not pulled down to a base pressure below 500um you probably have air in the system, the other problem common with overheating condensers is being over charged, this will cause the condenser to run very hot, what Freon type is in the system and with most fridges you only have a low side port what pressure did you charge to? What was the temp at that pressure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the condenser coil is reasonably clean, possibly a weak run capacitor on the compressor.  If you have made changes to the refrigerant such as you would be required to when replacing the dryer then more likely contamination with a noncondensible like air or overcharge of refrigerant.

Edit:  I have assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that you are in the US.  Voltage too high or frequency too low for the compressor rating could also cause the compressor and condenser to get very hot.

Comment: The motor on the compressor has built in thermal protection. When it overheats it trips out. Then after cooling it turns back on. Depending on the compressor there are many different reasons for a motor to overheat. Larger compressors have oil levels that need to be checked.

Comment: I agree with thermal overload being the problem. Things that can contribute are non compressible gasses in the system, you removed the dryer, was the system taken to at least 500um and verified there were no leaks prior to charging? Proper type and amount of refredgrant used? I think I accedently put 404a in a 134 system only took a few minutes to realise , had to clean the system and recharge with correct gas and now I have a couple of pounds of contaminated 404 in my recovery tank.